# (Flutter) Error: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe. (Using IFrameElement)

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am having this error when I move away from payment page below...

```
// Internal dependencies
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'dart:html' as html;
import 'dart:js' as js;
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

class Payment extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PaymentState createState() => _PaymentState();
}

String viewID = "aPayID";
String urlOnline = "hosted URL Somewhere";
String urlLocal = "http://localhost:3000/getPaymentMethods/";
bool online = true;

class _PaymentState extends State<Payment> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double total = Provider.of<CP>(context).getTotal();
    // ignore:undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
        viewID,
            (int id) {
             IFrameElement element= html.IFrameElement();
             window.onMessage.forEach((element) {
              
               print('Message Received in callback: ${element.data}');
                if(element.data=='Authorised'){
                  print("Sucessful payment");
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                } else if(element.data=='Pending'){
                  print('PAYMENT Pending');
                }else if(element.data=='Refused'){
                  print('PAYMENT Refused');
                }
             });
                element.width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width.toString();
                element.height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.toString();
                element.src = online? urlOnline+'${(total * 100).toInt()}' : urlLocal+'${(total * 100).toInt()}';
                element.style.border = 'none';
                return element;
            }
    );
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.white, //change your color here
        ),
        elevation: 0.0,
        title: Text("PAYMENT", style: Header),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.amber,
              child: HtmlElementView(
                viewType: viewID,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My Error message is as follows:

```
> Error: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe. At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable. To
> safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a
> reference to the ancestor by calling
> dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's
> didChangeDependencies() method.
>     at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:54312/dart_sdk.js:5279:11)...
```

I will really appreciate if someone can explain a little bit about what is happening here so I can learn something from this. Thanks

Comment: any update on this issue ? how did you overcome this one? thanks

Comment: Use something for pub.dev for this. There are many pre-built widgets ready to handle this situation.